# My .css file does not work on my webpage

Tags: html, css

Here is my.css code:

```
body {background-color:black;}
div.heading {text-align: center; background-color:white;border: 10px ridge grey;     margin-top:0px; font-size: 30px; font-family: Arial, Halvetica, sans-serif; color:black;}
```

The .css files name is Assignment 3.css

Here is my webpages code. The background is white, and the division is not displayed. If I make the style sheet internal then the code works, but as soon as i put the code in a separate notepad file it does not. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<style>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "Assignment 3.css">
</style>

<body>
<div class = "heading">
WELCOME TO BUILD A SQUARE
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: do not include spaces. choose something like "global.css" or "main.css". That is most probably your problem. Also, your link rel is inside `<style>` tags - move it out of it

Comment: I just tried linking `test file.css` and it worked, so its not the problem. @AndreSmith what is your directory structure?

Comment: Why does it work when i move it outside? because we were taught to always put the link rel inside style tags>

Comment: I guess your teacher needs to read a book on CSS. `link` should not be inside `style` EDIT: `style` tag acts like a substitute for external css file. You can write whatever's inside your `*.css` file inside `style` tag and then you dont have to link anything

Comment: it was my bad. not his! but thank you was helpful it sorted my problem out!

Comment: The `<link>` element is essentially unrelated to CSS, it can establish a relationship between your HTML document and other external resources such as javascript. More on `<link>` here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourfilename.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="heading">
WELCOME TO BUILD A SQUARE
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Style declarations such as `<link rel..>` need to be inside your `<head>` and as i mentioned before you shouldn't include spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Spaces are not valid URL characters. Either change your filename to `assignment3.css` or encode the space `Assignment%203.css`

Also move `<link>` out of `<style></style>`. That's invalid

Answer (score 1):

First thing to check is your file name, because the space may well cause a problem.

Try:

- renaming your css file to assignment-3.css
- update the link in the head of your page to
  `<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "assignment-3.css">`

If that still doesn't work, check that the css file exists at
  www.your-domain.com/assignment-3.css

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you put the link inside style tags. Try it inside the head.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

just remove the style   tag and it will work